# How to create a Button class that swells on other class object

Tags: c++, class, reference, hierarchy

I'm creating a little game in cpp, and I have trouble with my Button class:

```
class ids::Button : public ids::ASpriteObject {
    public:
        Button(std::vector<float> pos, std::string texture, int frame, std::function<void(Button&)> ptr, gameState &state);
        ~Button();
        std::string getType();
        void checkCollisions();
        void drawAsset(std::map<std::string, ModelS> modelMap);
        void launchGame();
        void settings();
        void exit();
        void mainMenu();
        void increaseSound();
        void decreaseSound();
        void increaseFPS();
        void decreaseFPS();

    protected:
    private:
        std::function<void(Button&)> _function;
        gameState &_gameState;
};
```

As you can see, a Button take a std::function in it's constructor. Thanks to it, I assign to the button the function which will be executed on click.

Here is my question: with my button, I want to modify other class object, like Text class for example:

```
class Text : public ids::AStaticObject {
    public:
        Text(std::vector<float> pos, std::string text, float size);
        ~Text();
        void drawAsset(std::map<std::string, ModelS> modelMap);

    protected:
    private:
        Font _font;
        std::string _text;
        Vector2 _pos;
        float _size;

};
```

on click, I want to modify the _text.
I can pass a reference to my Text object to my Button, but it's not smart, eventually I should modify other objects with my button...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the question? Are you aware that the `std::function` can hold a reference to the `Text` object for you?

Comment: hi!
i don't know, the std::function can take a reference to a method, but an object? what is the syntax for that?
thanks for your help!

Comment: and I can template this object because the button will not necessarily take a text?

Comment: I don't really get you point, maybe you want `std::bind` ?

Answer (score 1):

Given a reference to a `Text textObj`, you can create a callback that keeps a reference to `textObj` as follows:

```
auto callback = [&textObj](Button& b) {
  textObj.setText("hi there");
};

auto buttonPtr = new Button(pos, texture, frame, callback, state);
// or assign it to an object instance variable
```

Comment: It's exaclty what i'm searching for, thanks a lot!

Comment: sorry, but i can't find how to write the signature of the ctor of the button with the callback in parameter...